# Change syntax highlighting of individual file in netbeans

Tags: javascript, php, netbeans, syntax, highlighting

I have some javascript files with .php extension.  When I open them in Netbeans I'd like it to highlight things as if it were a .js file.  In Notepad++ I can just select the language in the menu and I'm good to go.  Is there a similar feature for Netbeans?

I don't want to change the highlighting for ALL php files, and I don't mind if I have to reselect the language each time I open the file as it's only one or two files.  Thanks.

Comment: 'netbeans-syntax-highlighting' [Changing your highlighting for differently named file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846514/netbeans-syntax-highlighting-for-volt-twig-and-php-in-phtml-files)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is what I'm after...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible for simple step.
- open NetBeans
- select tools tab
- select tools->options->fonts & colors->syntax->language
- select a language as per need and change the color of it

Comment: You have misunderstood my question.  I want to tell Netbeans that a file with a .php extension should be treated as a javascript file, not change the highlighting for a given language.